# Updating deployed VirtoCommerce-Template from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, tfs, e-commerce, virtocommerce

I recently deployed the gallery template of VirtoCommerce to an Azure website. Initially everything worked as it should - I even linked the site to a Team Foundation Server Project. After cloning the project to a local dev machine I proceeded to make a minor change and clicked publish. The publishing profile used was one provided by Azure. After a successful publish, I clicked on the link to the hosted site, however, the site eventually times out, and rarely returns a custom error page. A backup website was also created to ensure that I can at least connect to some server, as opposed to no server.

Site url: 'http://virtocommercedvt.azurewebsites.net/'

Site url: 'http://virtocommercebackup.azurewebsites.net/'

Any advice and / or suggestions that would allow me to update the website from within VS would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the settings not configured for the new site (search and database connection string). You can find them under "configure" tab in both website and cloud service.